# Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' that satisfies the version constraints

Tags: android, react-native

I have a problem with "react-native-geolocation-service" when I'm trying to compile my app in Android Studio.

```
  Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' that satisfies the version constraints: 
   Dependency path 'UnalAR:react-native-geolocation-service:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   Constraint path 'UnalAR:react-native-geolocation-service:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
   Dependency path 'UnalAR:react-native-geolocation-service:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   Constraint path 'UnalAR:react-native-geolocation-service:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
   Dependency path 'UnalAR:react-native-geolocation-service:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   Constraint path 'UnalAR:react-native-geolocation-service:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
   Dependency path 'UnalAR:react-native-geolocation-service:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   Constraint path 'UnalAR:react-native-geolocation-service:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
   Dependency path 'UnalAR:react-native-geolocation-service:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   Dependency path 'UnalAR:react-native-geolocation-service:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.8' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

My android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-simple-compass')
compile project(':react-native-heading')
compile project(':react-native-geolocation-service')
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
implementation project(':arcore_client') // remove this if AR not required
implementation project(':gvr_common')
implementation project(path: ':viro_renderer')
implementation project(path: ':react_viro')
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.1'
implementation 'com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:3.0.0-alpha-7'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.7.7'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.7.7'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.7.7'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.7.7'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.7.7' }
```

I followed the react-native-geolocation-service documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service), but this error only when i've include this library.

I think that the error is in

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

but I'm afraid to change it.

Thanks for help me guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Seeing the code of that project, it seems that it checks if you are overriding the version in your project (lots of dependencies started doing this when these issues appeared). So go into your project build.gradle (not the app/build.gradle) and you can override the version that library is using:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        ...
    }
}
```